Dynamic CI/CD variables not working in rules:changes:compare_to
I have a Gitlab pipeline and I want certain jobs to only run if certain files have changes from the previous commit. Here's my code:
.gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - local: .ci/container-images.yml
    rules:
      - changes:
          paths:
            - "ansible/**/*"
            - "docker/**/*"
          compare_to: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

.ci/container-images.yml
"build-docker-$[[ inputs.image ]]":
  rules:
    - changes:
        paths:
          - $[[ inputs.context ]]/**/*
        compare_to: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA

First I get this error for .gitlab-ci.yml:

include:rules:changes:compare_to is not a valid ref

Then if I set compare_to: main in .gitlab-ci.yml, I get this error from .ci/container-images.yml:

Failed to parse rule for build-docker-ansible-builder: rules:changes:compare_to is not a valid ref

I've tried manually entering a branch name & commit SHA and it works of course.
I'm confused about how these variables work, because according to this:

CI/CD variables are supported.

But then according to this:

Predefined variables made available by the runner cannot be used with trigger jobs or these keywords:

workflow
include
rules


So can I use the variables or not? I would find it very surprising that it's not possible to dynamically specify which ref to compare?
If variables are not allowed, is there another way to accomplish this?

Does main work if you use it like this: compare_to: 'main'

@MichaelKotzjan yes it works if I hard-code the branch name, but I'd much rather that be dynamic if possible

I was just asking since you said that putting compare_to: main would result in an error. I thought maybe you are just missing the ' before and after the name. But you now received a better answer :)

Sorry for the confusion! What I meant was when I used the variable (compare_to: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH) in .gitlab-ci.yml it would fail right away before it's able to include: .ci/container-images.yaml. But when I hard coded the branch (compare_to: main) it would proceed with the include: and then would fail with .ci/container-images.yml because that file has compare_to: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA.

Yes while surprising it does not currently support expansion of variables at the compare_to key. There's a tracking issue here.
It's been fixed and rolled out already, but judging from the comments seems like it won't come out until version 17.2 gets released
